# Show/Hide dojo grid columns

Tags: dojo, treegrid, dgrid

I have a screen where I have a matrix to display. I am using dgrid for it.
It has functionality to show/hide columns on the fly. User can show or hide any perticular column he wants. Also there is functionality of collapsible rows for which I have used TreeGrid of dgrid.
Please let me know if there is any way to implement this functionality.
You can check the screenshot below to understand my query.
![enter image description here][1]

dGrid to be implemented which show hide column functionality

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want is the ColumnHider extension, already included in the dgrid repository
inside de externsions folder.

also your mesage is kinda cryptic, so its dificult to answer

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the @user3655423 's query without using the columnHider feature. Because i don't want to give the user the privilege to hide/show columns. I just want to show a fixed (say 4) columns of the grid(reusable) in one page and just 3 columns of the same grid in an other page.

Comment: how about having a base column definition(3 columns example) and an IF statement that pushes to the definition if you satisfy the 4 column condition. E.g. var myColumns = {
        first: {
            label: "First Name"
        },
        last: {
            label: "Last Name"
        }
    }; if(/*some condition*/){ myColumns.third = {
            label: "Other Name"
        }; /*more pushes if necesary*/ } /*initialize grid*/

Comment: Thanks for that. That's one good way. Right now I have just hid the columnHider icon (+) to prevent the user from making the change ; )